# Apache doesn't accept the key for a certificate when that certificate is bundled with its issuer

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, openssl, pki

I am setting up a Certificate Authority for an intranet. There is a root certificate which will be installed on all the network machines, an intermediate certificate signed by the root, and a http server certificate signed by the intermediate.

I need to bundle the http and intermediate certificates in order for them to be validated by the root

```
#> cat intermediate.crt server.crt > both.crt
#> openssl verify -CAfile root.crt both.crt
OK
```

However, I can't use `both.crt` and `server.private.key` for the internal website because when apache starts:

```
Certificate and private key mysite.com:443:0 from /www/both.crt and /www/server.private.key do not match
```

This is because `intermediate.crt` is the first entry in `both.crt`. If I switch the order of `server.crt` and `intermediate.crt` then apache launches but `both.crt` won't validate against `root.crt`.

The requirement is that `root.crt` is installed permanently, but `server.crt` and `intermediate.crt` are subject to change and need to be served ad hoc by apache. How do I construct a certificate bundle which apache accepts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the server certificate as the argument to the `SSLCertificateFile` directive and a file containing all subordinate CAs, excluding Root CA, as an argument to `SSLCertificateChainFile`.  Finally, the private key for your server certificate as the argument to `SSLCertificateKeyFile`:

```
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/bundle.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/server.key
```

Comment: Also note that one should *not* `cat intermediate.crt server.crt > both.crt` but instead validate `server.crt` *only* against the chain.

Comment: [this advice](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/create-the-intermediate-pair.html#create-the-certificate-chain-file) is to include the root in the chain, contrary to what you said. Does it really matter?

Comment: There is no need to include the Root in the chain as it _must_ be installed on the relying party for it to trust the chain.  Or, to look at it another way, if the Root CA cert isn't installed on the relying party, then adding it to the bundle won't help - it still won't trust the chain.